# Name for this type of Markov process?

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, definition

I'm experimenting with this type of stochastic process and I'm wondering if there is a specific name for it. So far I've described it as a *discrete-time continuous-state Markov process* but curious to see if there's a special name. I have random variables $X_t$ where $t \in \mathbb{N}$ on the state-space $\mathbb{R}$, given by:

$X_{t+1}=
    \begin{cases}
      0, & \text{with prob.}\ \alpha \\
      X_t +\mu, & \text{with prob.}\ 1-\alpha
    \end{cases}$

where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Before pondering what name this has: Your process jumps back to zero and otherwise attains only the values $\mu\mathbb N\,.$ I believe it may as well be called a discrete-state MP. What is the background? A name never fully describes a thing completely.

Comment: Fair point. I guess my question was more about whether there was a name for the general structure of this stochastic process. I have also been thinking about other specifications where the state space is continuous, e.g where $\mu$ is instead random normal.